# Setting release configuration for SPA / webpack

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, webpack

I'm developing a Single Page Application and using Webpack for bundling up the modules.

One of my source files (I'm using TypeScript) has settings and configuration used in the application e.g.

```
// app-settings.ts
export class AppSettings {
    public static ApiUrlPrefix: string = "//localhost/myapi/";
}
```

Which I then use in my code like:

```
//some-class.ts
import {AppSettings} from "./app-settings"

export class SomeClass {
    contructor() {
       var something = AppSettings.ApiUrlPrefix;
    }
}
```

When release time comes, I'm going to want the settings to match the live environment.

What's a good way with either gulp, npm or webpack configs to update the settings file? I've seen the HtmlWebpackPlugin which can take a template and plug in some options, so I guess I'm looking for something similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `webpack.DefinePlugin`. The Define plugin allows you to pass "Free Global" or "macro-like" variables into your project that you can use. To use `webpack.DefinePlugin` simply `require()` `webpack` into your project.

Here's [the documentation and an example on how to use it](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/list-of-plugins#defineplugin).